# How to connect Openfire with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, xmpp, openfire

I know I can connect using the smack library, but is there another way? I can't find any current sources on this subject. Most code examples are written in Java. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.igniterealtime.smack/smack-android Also, when I add the latest version to the dependencies here, I get an error in the codes.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    
    fun connectToXMPPServer() {
        val config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setUsernameAndPassword("your_username", "your_password")
            .setXmppDomain("your_xmpp_domain")
            .setHost("your_xmpp_host")
            .setPort(5222) // XMPP port number
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled) // You may need to adjust security mode
            .build()

        val connection = XMPPTCPConnection(config)

        val config = XMPPConnection.FromMode.entries
        try {
            connection.connect()
            connection.login()
            // XMPP connection is established and authenticated
        } catch (e: SmackException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            // Handle connection errors
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?